# MVP, set the view of the presenter to null on destroy?

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2

I am currently trying to implement the MVP pattern on Android. However, I came to think about memory leaks (since the presenter holds a reference to the activity - the view). My question is, should I set the view of the presenter to null say onDestroy of the activity?

This is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainView {
private Button loadUser;
private TextView mTextView;
@Inject
IMainPresenter mPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpViews();

    ((MyApp) getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
    mPresenter.setView(this);
}

private void setUpViews() {
    loadUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getUserBtn);
    loadUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mPresenter.loadUserName(2);
        }
    });
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userNameTextView);
}

@Override
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    mTextView.setText(userName);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mPresenter.setView(null);
}
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Comment: @MohsenMirhoseiniArgi Thank you for the links! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always did like that, I mean, I always set the view to null on the `onDestroy()` method. I try to use the [LightCycle](https://github.com/soundcloud/lightcycle) library to avoid having to code all that boilerplate code. Here's an article that explains Fernando Ceja's [Clean Architecture](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/). This is an MVP architecture widely used (I've worked in a couple of companies that use this pattern), there you can see that he also sets the view to null in the `onDestroy()` method. Let me know if I can help you any further.

**UPDATE:**

This answer is kinda outdated, now you can use the LifecycleOwner class from the Android's Jetpack tools. It's basically the same deal but with different API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what you are suggesting is creating a method onDestroy in my presenter class where I am setting the presenter's reference to the view - activity to null and I am calling this method in my activitiie's onDestroy?

Comment: Yeah, that will do the work. Remember to check that the view field reference in your Presenter is != null before calling any view method. BTW are you planning to add unit testing in your project?

Comment: Perfect! Yes, that was the main reason to implement the MVP pattern, it is easier to test (so I have read)

Comment: Yes is really easy to test this way. Basically you will have an `InteractorModule` or `UseCaseModule` where you declare all your use cases, later you can extend from that *Module class and override the methods to return the mocked versions instead of the real ones. You can use Mockito to mock the interactors. If you have any doubt about this, make a new question and share the link here, I'll try to explain this more in detail.

Comment: @4gus71n So why do you recommend setting the view to null in onDestroy() ? What would happen if the view is NOT set to null? I would appreciate it very much if you could explain your recommendation some more.

Comment: @Monica Hey, I updated my answer since the LightCycle library is kinda deprecated right now. If you don't set your view variable to null in the onDestroy(), what's gonna happen is that, for example, an EventBus event from some other place could get trigger, get handled by your Presenter and then the view variable is gonna get called, if the method from the view's variable is using some UI widget, the instance of that widget is gonna be null, hence NPE. Something like that.

Comment: @4gus71n Thanks for the quick response. In your example, with the EventBus event, when you say "from some other place", do you mean from a different app on the phone?

Comment: @Monica No, I was thinking "from some other place" like an IntentService, stand alone service, another Presenter or an Interactor's callback. Imagine that you have two screens each one with its Presenter and Its UI (Fragment/Activity). First screen is a building list, second screen is the building detail. If you change something in the detail, like the building's name, you want to reflect that in the list, right? You do it through EventBus, firing one event from one Presenter and catching it in the other.

Comment: This answer helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that you are using an Injection library (probably Dagger looking at your code) and the `Presenter` is annotated with `@Singleton`? If so, then setting to null is one option (and yes you should not be retaining an `Activity` instance on configuration changes).

Another option is to use a `WeakReference` in your `Presenter` that way setting to `null` is not required, although setting to `null` is more explicit.

You might consider using Interfaces with your `Presenter` rather than exposing the whole `Activity` to the Presenter instance - you may already be doign something like this, but not 100% clear from code provided.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I might consider that as an option since null-setting approach is not very reliable (I might forget to set it to null somewhere in my classes). Yes, I am using interfaces as well. I intentionally did not mentioned for simplicity and brivity reasons :p

Answer (score 2):

Could you not make the presenter lifecycle aware using https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html ? The presenter could then itself be responsible for setting the view to null when onDestroy() is called on the view.

Comment: This is also a viable option :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set the view(Activity) to `null` then your presenter is going to continue holding the reference to Activity.
I will use Activity as an example but the same works for Fragments.

## Is this a problem and why?

It depends on the lifecycle of the presenter. You need to understand how long does your presenter live in memory.

**Case 1:**

If your presenter is defined as Singleton (which I think you shouldn't be doing) then it stays in memory as long as the app itself.

**This is a problem** because then a singleton class will hold a reference to Activity, which consequently prevents it from ever being garbage collected. When your Activity is destroyed, it will be useless to the user, but will still occupy memory (RAM). Apart from taking precious memory, the presenter might receive events like successful API response, which will trigger a `view.doSomething` method, which can cause crashes (working with destroyed Activity's UI is not something you should ever do, the Android framework will throw exceptions).

Generally, Presenters are not so widely scoped so it's not an issue. If your presenters are scoped to live longer than Activity, you need to manually set the view reference to null to solve the problem.

**Case 2:**

Your Presenter might not be defined as a Singleton, but some other Singleton, or similar widely scoped component might be holding a reference to your Presenter, making it live longer than Activity.

You might have something like `Eventbus` or `UserRepository` or `UserController` Singleton class. Your Presenter might hold a reference to such object and be subscribed to it. When you subscribe, you're basically setting a reference of yourself to that other class. In Presenter, when you call  `eventbus.subscribe(this)` or `userRepository.setListener(this)`, you're giving a Singleton a reference to yourself. Singleton object holding a reference to your object makes your object in memory as long as the Singleton object lives, which is forever.
If you're using lambdas, anonymous classes, or nested classes, such constructs hold a reference to their enclosing class, it may cause the following chain of references:
`Singleton->Anonymous class->Presenter->Activity`

In such case, Singleton indirectly references an Activity, preventing it from being garbage collected!

Instead of `userRepository.setListener(this)`, you might be using something like this:

```
userRepository.updateUser(object: Listener {
   onSuccess() {
      // do something
   }
   onFailure() {}
})
```

Let's say the updateUser method does a long operation (sends an API request). In such case, the reference is kept only while the update user request is in progress. When onSuccess or onFailure is invoked the reference is *typically* (implementations may vary) cleared. So here, a memory leak problem is not such a big of a deal, as the reference will be cleared, only with a slight delay. However, you still have the issue of updating the view after it is destroyed(described in Case 1) - you can reproduce it by exiting the activity while the request is in progress.

To solve the described issues, you need to use something like `userRepository.clear()` or `eventbus.unsubscribe(this)`. The implementations of such methods should cancel all in-flight requests and remove the references to subscriber/listener (presenter).
If you do it right, you don't even need to set presenter's view reference to null. Garbage collector is smart enough to figure out your Activity and Presenter objects are holding reference to each other, but no other component is holding reference to them and delete both of them from Memory.
However, my recommendation is to do it anyway, since it's an easy operation which does not have to be repeated everywhere (can be done in BasePresenter class) and may save you if you forget to clear some reference manually.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1.**

If Presenter's lifetime is not longer then Activity's, there is no need to set view to null. The important part is to stop background thread where your presenter executes its work. If you stop Presenter's background thread in onDestroy, then the thread is terminated and doesn't keep a link to the Activity anymore. So both Activity and Presenter can be collected by GC soon.

This scenario can often be found in the projects which use MVP and don't handle orientation change.

**Scenario 2.**

If Presenter's can live longer than Activity (e.g., singleton), then you should set View to null. [Here cases like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59270509/3129644) are described.

If you want presenter's thread survive configuration change you most likely make you presenter lifetime longer then activity's.

---

A would recommend you to switch to [MVVM](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) instead of MVP. If you use Google Architecture components in a right way, Lifecycle-aware components will unsubscribe your Views and stop threads for you.