# Object reference changes when called from onPropertyChanged(DataBinding Android)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mvp, android-databinding

```
public class FilterFragmentExp extends BaseFragmentFilter implements ListingMVPview{
    @Inject PresenterListing presenterExp;
    private FilterUtilsModel filterModel;
    private ListingModel listingModel,listingModel_tmp;

    public static FilterFragmentExp newInstance(FilterUtilsModel filterModel,ListingModel listingModel) {
        FilterFragmentExp fragment = new FilterFragmentExp();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("filter",filterModel);
        bundle.putSerializable("listing",listingModel);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getComponent().inject(this);
        presenterExp.attachView(this);
        receiveArguments();
        filterModel.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPropertyChanged(Observable observable, int i) {
                presenterExp.initialize(filterModel.getExpMap(),TYPE_EXP);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        presenterExp.detachView();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.fragment_filter_exp;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterUtilsModel getFilter() {
    }

    private void receiveArguments(){
        filterModel = (FilterUtilsModel) getArguments().getSerializable("filter");
        listingModel = (ListingModel) getArguments().getSerializable("listing");
        listingModel_tmp = listingModel;
    }



    @Override
    public void showLoading() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hideLoading() {

    }

    @Override
    public void showRetry() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hideRetry() {

    }

    @Override
    public void showError(String message) {

    }
}
```

When I moved to this fragment for the first time everything works well, but from next time(pressed back and come back again) I am getting a nullpointer exception from this line -

```
presenterExp.initialize(filterModel.getExpMap(),TYPE_EXP);
```

**I am supposed to get this error only if I wont set any view(MVP view, here its ListingMVPview) to the presenter object(presenterExp)**, but I already set it on this line

```
presenterExp.attachView(this);
```

Here is my Presenter -

```
    public class PresenterListing extends BasePresenter<ListingMVPview> {
        private final Context context;

        @Inject
        public PresenterListing(@ActivityContext Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void attachView(ListingMVPview mvpView) {
            super.attachView(mvpView);
        }

        @Override
        public void detachView() {
            super.detachView();
        }
        public void initialize(Map options, String type) {
            getMVPView().showLoading();
            this.getListing(options,type);
        }
....
    }
```

Here in the above code getMVPView() returning null, though I have set MVP view.

I have used Dagger2 for dependency injection and using constructor injection for creating **PresenterListing** objects and using MVP architecture.

Any clues would be helpful as this problem is happening on when called from  onPropertyChanged, if I move the code to some other place(say on some view's onclicklistener) everything works fine

Comment: In the code you don't show how you set the View. I'd guess your issues is related to the lifecycle of the Fragment. Or its recreation.

Comment: in the BasePresenter class I am just holding the value received in attachView(ListingMVPview mvpView) and on calling detachView making it null

Answer (score 0):

you can add a null judgement

`if (null) {...`

advise start to use [google mvp](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-contentproviders), good lucky

Comment: I can do that, in fact interestingly if I remove presenterExp.detachView(); line from onDestroy() everything works fine. I want to know why its happenning?????

Comment: presenterExp.detachView() just changing the MVP view reference in the presenterExp to null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204527/mvp-set-the-view-of-the-presenter-to-null-on-destroy hope to heplyou, i like google mvp

Comment: updated my question, here I think the problem is happening in the onPropertyChanged section